# I had a problem with looping a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

My code snippet's purpose is to reveal an animation while the scrollY is on 0 if the scrollY is above 0 it will reveal other animations, however, the code only works once.

```
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar");
  var i = 0;
  for ( i; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    } else if (window.scrollY == 0) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("nactive");
    } else {
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
reveal();
```

the function needs to be looped but I don't know how.

Comment: You keep adding the classes `active` and `nactive`, but you never remove them.

Comment: And you manually call the function after setting it in the event listener (could be done on purpose, tho)

Comment: By the way, if there is nothing in the `else` part, you can simply remove it

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH MAN ,yall really make my day.